# Find and Pull data from API (elgg)

Tags: javascript, api, events, elgg

Okay so I'm trying to make a custom elgg website.
One of the main features I need is for users to be able to create events, and for those events to be displayed in a sortable table.

For events, I use a plugin for elgg called Event Manager. I originally thought that the data for the events was stored in mysql, but apparently it's stored in the elgg API instead.
'
Can anyone give me any tips on where to find the event data, and how to pull it from the api and put it into a javascript/html table?

Gracias,
Pablo Escobar

Answer (score 1):

Regarding details of writing plugins, refer to documentation: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Main_Page and make sure to read through: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Engine/DataModel

To get event_calendar events, you'll need to use one of the functions from [elgg_get_entities](http://reference.elgg.org/entities_8php.html#af085c8362e49c4f52d4f1fcf58ca6fb8) family. You'll most likely need to filter by type (object) and subtype (event_calendar), apply some filtering (`metadata_name_value_pairs` parameter to [elgg_get_entities_from_metadata](http://reference.elgg.org/engine_2lib_2metadata_8php.html#aec4b6f0b9565e3554acb9b39ef34a2ac)) and sorting (`order_by_metadata`)

For additional support you'll be more successful at community.elgg.org page.